# Extending the width of a table on both sides

Tags: tables

I am having trouble extending the with of a table. I need the width of my table to be wider than text width and based on my search results a command like following should do it:

```
\begin{tabular*}{1.2\textwidth}
```

The problem with such code is that it only extends the width of my table on right side and it would look like this:

[image]

How can I make it to extend on both sides?

Thanks

Comment: Is the shown image the desired result? Why waste that much space at the left margin of the table, i.e. below `Algorithms/Networks`?

Comment: Could you provide the example code to replicate your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, caption}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.1\textwidth}{-0.1\textwidth}
\caption{Some totally uninformative caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | rl | }
\hline
\lipsum[11]\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
& test text 
& tests texts \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]